# Complex sql query for only returning another tables data after AND clause

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am having trouble only getting one tables rows:

Here is my code

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM User_Skills ,User_Profile WHERE User_Skills.UserId = User_Profile.UserId AND User_Profile.country = %s AND User_Profile.state= %s AND USER_Profile.city= %s", (LocAll[0],LocAll[1],LocAll[2]) )
```

How do I say. Get the users who come from country y (found in the profile table) and return the rows in the user skills tables.

That said I also don’t want to have to type all the column eg if there where 100 columns for example hence I used *.

Not sure if this is the correct way to start with or whether who should rather use joins etc.

thank you.

Comment: Why are you using raw queries in django?

Comment: I am using an algorithm to process data in a script, hence I am first building out the basics by testing sql return values... It easier for me to understand the inner working by making raw queries than django magic... As I am new to the platform and also like knowing whats going on , so its a lack of experience I guess--- hope that helps

Comment: I tried this but it keeps giving a syntax error: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM User_Skills LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Profile ON User_Skills.UserId = User_profile.UserId WHERE User_Skills.UserId = User_Profile.UserId AND User_Profile.country = %s AND User_Profile.state= %s AND USER_Profile.city= %s", (LocAll[0],LocAll[1],LocAll[2]) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you want to know is how to select all columns from a table without typing them out.  If so, try `User_Skills.*` instead of just `*`.

Comment: Hi thanks so much I tried that but I get an error... I placed this code in psql and it does what it should but not using cursor and pyscopg2 it keeps joing the rows with data and the out put is a long list of it... could this be a bug?cur.execute("SELECT * FROM User_Skills ab LEFT JOIN User_Profile cd ON ab.UserId = cd.UserId WHERE cd.country = %s AND cd.state = %s AND cd.city = %s", (LocAll[0],LocAll[1],LocAll[2]))

Comment: I think you should repost this question tagging it as a python django sql problem, with a complete copy of your code, but it sounds like you're just missing a line break in your print statements.  Need to see the output and the code to really figure it out though (so make a new question).